# I can run better after swimming, how come?

Tags: running, cardio, stretching, swimming

I found out that when I go swimming in the evening (from 5:30 - 6:30), that my running (from 8:30 - 9:30) seems to go a lot better.

(Eg. I'm less tired, I have less need for stretching - I stretch to suppress the soreness in my legs ;) because I haven't been running for long).

But how is this possible? I thought my body would be more tired after swimming.

Comment: This is interesting to me. I found this answer searching for just the opposite answer. I found that I can swim much better after running a couple of miles. My breathing seems to be regulated better, so I don't get so tired in the water. This is strange. It's so drastic, I can go almost 10 times as far swimming without stopping if I run before getting in the water.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several factors are involved:

- Your body warmed up enough --> thus less need for stretching
- Swimming actually regulates your breathing system, it is like some sort of "heavy" yoga breathing session, specially if you "crawl" or do "Butterfly Stroke" which both require some time below water and thus deep breathing when above water to recuperate. Thus you breath much better and sharper after a swimming session ---> breathing is needed while running, so you already got the boost from swimming
- You are **either** having a balanced diet **| or** enough calories for energy  **| or** in case you have fat reserves that will be fueling your energy for running  after swimming (After one hour of swimming, if you did not load yourself during the day with calories, your body must be already getting energy from fat reserves and it continues to do that when u go run).
  In each of these cases , you already have some energy left to burn for running.

The 3 factors mentioned put you in a "good" state for running. **PS:** make sure you dry well after swimming before running specially if you live on the beach, night sea winds are fresh and if you didn't dry well you might get sore muscles the next day.

Comment: Awesome, i'm trying to slim down (gained some weight while working during 2 years) and it seems that swimming before running is just a good idea ;-) - between the swimming and running i didn't eat, just a protein shake and some melon. I ate lightly after running (no carbs in the evening). -although, i have to disagree on one thing, my body warmed up. According to my belief, you won't lose lots of weight while swimming, because the water cools down you're body and there is 2 hours in between :). PS. I go crawl, so you're right! :)

Comment: @NicoJuicy two things: a) even if the water is cool, if you swim vigorously (sport swimming, not swimming to chill) your muscles will heavily warm up , so will your body. b) If you measure your diet and what you eat, swimming does help you loose weight because it involves muscles strength and burn a lot of calories on top, plus swimming will give you a shape that body building (for example) alone won't give you. It gives you a good posture. Slimming down is a combination of two factors: diet and exercising, and swimming is an amazing exercise from my own experience

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the overall temp of the body has dropped, and hence it takes longer to heat up and then you sweat less and dont dehydrate as quick.
I'm doing a 8k race tomorrow and will have a swim first, just for 15  min...